# Calibrating data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a grouped dataset which I would like to recalibrate to provide more datapoints for analysis. Essentially, I want to add the positive equivalents of the least number (a negative number) in each group to all the numbers within that group. Please note that I only want this rule applied to groups containing negative numbers only. For example, in the dataframe A below, the rule does not need to be applied to A1 as it doesn't contain any negative numbers.

Here's a sample dataframe:

```
x_1 <- c("A1", "A1","A1", "B10", "B10", "B10","B10", "B500", "C100", "C100", "C100",     
"D40", "G100", "G100")


z_1 <- c(1.1, 1.4, 1.6, -1.0, -2.2, 3, 2.3, 2.0, -3.4, -4.1, 2, 2, 2.4, -3.5)


A <- data.frame(x_1, z_1)

x_1   z_1
A1    1.1
A1    1.4
A1    1.6
B10  -1.0
B10  -2.2
B10   3.0
B10   2.3
B500  2.0
C100 -3.4
C100 -4.1
C100  2.0
D40   2.0
G100  2.4
G100 -3.5
```

The result I would like to achieve is given by the dataframe B below:

```
b_2 <- c(1.1, 1.4, 1.6, 0, 1.2, 4.5, 5.2, 2.0, 0, 0.7, 6.1, 2.0, 0, 5.9)

B <- data.frame(x_1, b_2)


x_1  b_2
A1   1.1
A1   1.4
A1   1.6
B10  0.0
B10  1.2
B10  4.5
B10  5.2
B500 2.0
C100 0.0
C100 0.7
C100 6.1
D40  2.0
G100 0.0
G100 5.9
```

For example, to obtain `b_2[4:7]`, I added 2.2 to all the other numbers, etc.

I have started off by ordering the data using `G <- A[order(A$x_1, A$z_1), ]` but I'm not aware of any other function that I can use to execute this task. The match function would not be of much use here.

I've done a brief search but I still don't know what else to use here. I would therefore warmly welcome any useful suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(A)[, list(z_1, z_1a=z_1 - min(0, z_1)), by=x_1]
#      x_1  z_1 z_1a
#  1:   A1  1.1  1.1
#  2:   A1  1.4  1.4
#  3:   A1  1.6  1.6
#  4:  B10 -1.0  1.2
#  5:  B10 -2.2  0.0
#  6:  B10  3.0  5.2
#  7:  B10  2.3  4.5
#  8: B500  2.0  2.0
#  9: C100 -3.4  0.7
# 10: C100 -4.1  0.0
# 11: C100  2.0  6.1
# 12:  D40  2.0  2.0
# 13: G100  2.4  5.9
# 14: G100 -3.5  0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, there's no need to `order` your data first. Just use `ave` and `min` within `within`:

```
within(A, {
  Mods <- ave(z_1, x_1, FUN = min)
  Mods[Mods > 0] <- 0
  Mods <- abs(Mods)
  z_2 <- z_1 + Mods
  rm(Mods)
})
#     x_1  z_1 z_2
# 1    A1  1.1 1.1
# 2    A1  1.4 1.4
# 3    A1  1.6 1.6
# 4   B10 -1.0 1.2
# 5   B10 -2.2 0.0
# 6   B10  3.0 5.2
# 7   B10  2.3 4.5
# 8  B500  2.0 2.0
# 9  C100 -3.4 0.7
# 10 C100 -4.1 0.0
# 11 C100  2.0 6.1
# 12  D40  2.0 2.0
# 13 G100  2.4 5.9
# 14 G100 -3.5 0.0
```

---

A more direct approach (that *generously* borrows from @BrodieG's answer) is to change the `within` stuff to a more straightforward:

```
with(A, z_1 - ave(z_1, x_1, FUN = function(x) min(0, min(x))))
```

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto, thanks so much for your answer-I had no idea the ave function existed. I'll read up on it,

Comment: Adapting @BrodieG's answer to `ave`, we can do something like `with(A, z_1 - ave(z_1, x_1, FUN = function(x) min(0, min(x))))` to get the values we need.

Comment: + 1 for base; I think it's good practice to stick to base if you have a clean solution, which I think with the `min` trick you very much do.  I keep forgetting about `ave`